# Override node title validation

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I have a pretty specific case where I want to fill in the node title myself if the user fills a checkbox above the title field.

For this reason, I can't use autonodetitle (because the title is only automatic if the checkbox is selected).

I have added my own validation callback using array_unshift() in a hook_form_alter to make sure its the first one but when its called the form already has an error (title field is required)

Is there any way I hook into the validation process earlier or even just remove the error for this field?

Thanks!

Comment: where did you add the array_unshift(), in a hook_form_alter()? Also, feel free to share what is the error.

Comment: yeah in a hook_form_alter(), the error is that title field can't be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily hook into the validation process by implementing [`hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or it's cousin [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). There you can inspect the `$form` variable, find out where the array of validation functions is, and perform `array_unshift()` on it.

You could also use the form alter hooks to modify the [`#required`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#required) property of your title field, therefore preventing further validation errors down the line.

Don't forget that in order for your `array_unshift()` operation to be successful, the form needs to be passed by reference to your hook, or else you would only be modifying a local copy of the form variable. It's very easy to forget adding the ampersand `&` in front of `$form` in the hook implementation. i.e. ...`& $form`...

Comment: I already did that and no go! :(

Comment: If you put `error_log(__FUNCTION__)` in each of the functions mentioned in the validator array, what do you get? Is your validator truly the first? If it is, then your problem is beyond `hook_form_alter()` and it might lie in some core code. If it not the first, then you might be missing a step from my solution.

Comment: If you can confirm 100% that your validator is the first, and by the time you break into your validator you have an error in the form, then most likely [form_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_error/7) is being called outside a validator (read: no-no, naughty code). If this is indeed the case, then just break into `form_error()` and see who's calling it.

Comment: Also, have you checked out [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7)? I've never used it, but could it be that the form you are targeting has a base form, which also specifies a "base form validator"?

Comment: Good catch, I'll try that out!

Comment: Turns out I was already using a hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter, still no go, by the time it reaches my validation callback it already has the error

Comment: Wow. That's one tricky error! Well, like I said, most likely form_error() is getting called. To find out who's calling it first, feel free to drop a [debug_bactrakce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) in it, and then you can take it from there.